# Unable to create text file using Android Studio Kotlin. Neither able to build apk with text file manually added via gradle

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, android-appcompat

I am new to kotlin.

I normally used val file = "Data.txt" that easily creates the file. But now the app is almost completed I noticed that code is not able to create file anymore. Whenever I tries to create file (execute it with a button and app crashes). With so many errors (one of them) "java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/user/0/com.example.waterledger/files/Data.txt (No such file or directory)"

When I locate the folder and manually added the file there. The app works without any problem (it easily read, writes, modify the file "Data.txt") but when I build apk it didn't get that text file that is manually created via gradle so the app crashes when I press the button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that is the proper way to create a file in Kotlin. What your code is doing is simply creating a variable named file whose value is "data.txt".
However, Kotlin provides a number of methods to create files. One of them is the writeText() method. So you could create your file like this using the writeText() method

```
val fileName = "data.txt"      


var file = File(fileName)
file.writeText("")
```

The "" will simply give an empty string, as argument to writeText(), to write data to file. You may provide the string you would like to write into this file.

Comment: Sorry to write incomplete code.
val file = "data.txt"

var fileOutputStream: FileOutputStream

try {
    fileOutputStream = openFileOutput(file, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
}

catch (e: FileNotFoundException) {
  e.printStackTrace()
    }
catch (e: Exception) {
e.printStackTrace()
}
That's creating file. The problem is different from what I asked (I discovered it lately) Need to call fileinstream before fileoutstream so that data written in the file saved first than updated with new values. Running instream states "file not found", running outstream first wipes/clears the file. Thanks

Comment: can you show me how you declared the file instream

Comment: `code` Read the text values from file (old values to be updated)
var file = "data.txt"
var fileInputStream: FileInputStream? = null
fileInputStream = openFileInput(file)
val inputStreamReader = InputStreamReader(fileInputStream)
val bufferedReader = BufferedReader(inputStreamReader)
val StringBuilder: StringBuilder = StringBuilder()
var text: String? = null
while ({ text = bufferedReader.readLine(); text }() != null) {
                    StringBuilder.append(text).append("\n")
                }

Comment: `code`(write new values + old values in text file)
var fileOutputStream: FileOutputStream
try {
fileOutputStream = openFileOutput(file, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
fileOutputStream.write(StringBuilder.toString().toByteArray())
fileOutputStream.write(datePicker.toByteArray())
fileOutputStream.write(space.toByteArray())
fileOutputStream.write(calcula2.toByteArray())
} catch (e: FileNotFoundException) {
e.printStackTrace()
} catch (e: Exception) {
e.printStackTrace()
}

Comment: This API (`File.writeText { ... }` ) no longer exists as of "2.0.0-Beta4". Aloha.